# Decrease in bulb brightness on connecting appliances in parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

In my textbook, it says that if you connect another appliance in parallel to a light bulb in a circuit with current I flowing through it(initially), the net voltage drops across the parallel connection and the power drawn by the bulb would decrease according to $P=\frac{V^2}{R}$.

However, the current I flowing through the bulb is treated as constant throughout the process. Isn't that wrong? Doesn't the loss in potential imply a corresponding loss in current flowing through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an erratum, since it is not possible to change the voltage throught the bulb without changing the current through it if the resistance can be assumed constant. By Ohm’s law ($I= V/R$), a decrease in voltage should be accompanied by a decrease in current. See also this related question [will a bulb grow brighter...](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219907/will-a-bulb-glow-brighter-if-voltage-is-increased-but-current-remains-the-same)